# 'Kubelet stopped posting node status' and node inaccessible

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I am having some issues with a fairly new cluster where a couple of nodes (always seems to happen in pairs but potentially just a coincidence) will become NotReady and a `kubectl describe` will say that the Kubelet stopped posting node status for memory, disk, PID and ready.

All of the running pods are stuck in Terminating (can use k9s to connect to the cluster and see this) and the only solution I have found is to cordon and drain the nodes. After a few hours they seem to be being deleted and new ones created. Alternatively I can delete them using kubectl.

They are completely inaccessible via ssh (timeout) but AWS reports the EC2 instances as having no issues.

This has now happened three times in the past week. Everything does recover fine but there is clearly some issue and I would like to get to the bottom of it.

How would I go about finding out what has gone on if I cannot get onto the boxes at all? (Actually just occurred to me to maybe take a snapshot of the volume and mount it so will try that if it happens again, but any other suggestions welcome)

Running kubernetes v1.18.8

Comment: What if you do a kubectl describe nodes ?

Comment: It just tells me that the Kubelet has stopped posting node status for pretty much everything but not other information

Comment: @OllyW Could you please check the status of your resources when this happens? Does it occurs when load is high? Do you run out of memory or disk space?

Comment: OK I have tracked it down to a huge upsurge in iops so moved the nodes to io1 rather than gp2 whilst I investigate further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be an issue with iops as a result of du commands coming from - I think - cadvisor. I have moved to io1 boxes and have had stability since then so going to mark this as closed and the move of ec2 instance types as the resolution

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Afraid not. I had already checked OOM issues and seen the max streams one and neither were apparent as the problem. The issue wasn't really with the high iops but with the instances' ability to deal with it

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue, could you please detail your answer to include how you determined this and how to investigate further?

Answer (score 3):

There are two most common possibilities here, both most likely caused by a large load:

- `Out of Memory` error on the kubelet host. Can be solved by adding proper `--kubelet-extra-args` to `BootstrapArguments`. For example: `--kubelet-extra-args "--kube-reserved memory=0.3Gi,ephemeral-storage=1Gi --system-reserved memory=0.2Gi,ephemeral-storage=1Gi --eviction-hard memory.available<200Mi,nodefs.available<10%"`
- An issue explained [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/74302#issuecomment-467359176):

> kubelet cannot patch its node status sometimes, ’cos more than 250
> resources stay on the node, kubelet cannot watch more than 250 streams
> with kube-apiserver at the same time. So, I just adjust kube-apiserver
> --http2-max-streams-per-connection to 1000 to relieve the pain.

You can either adjust the values provided above or try to find the cause of high load/iops and try to tune it down.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, after 20-30 min my nodes became in `NotRready` status, and all pods linked to these nodes became stuck in `Terminating` status.
I tried to connect to my nodes via SSH, sometimes I faced a timeout, sometimes I could (hardly) connect, and I executed the `top` command to check the running processes.
The most consuming process was `kswapd0`.
My instance memory and CPU were both full (!), because it tried to swap a lot (due to a lack of memory), causing the `kswapd0` process to consume more than 50% of the CPU!

**Root cause**:
Some pods consumed 400% of their memory request (defined in Kubernetes deployment), because they were initially under-provisioned. As a consequence, when my nodes started, Kubernetes placed them on nodes with only 32Mb of memory request per pod (the value I had defined), but that was insufficient.

**Solution**:
The solution was to increase containers requests:

```
requests:
  memory: "32Mi"
    cpu: "20m"
    limits:
       memory: "256Mi"
       cpu: "100m"
```

With these values (in my case):

```
requests:
  memory: "256Mi"
    cpu: "20m"
    limits:
       memory: "512Mi"
       cpu: "200m"
```

**Important**:
After that I processed a rolling update (*cordon* > *drain* > *delete*) of my nodes in order to ensure that Kubernetes reserve directly enough memory for my freshly started pods.

**Conclusion**:
Regularly check your pods' memory consumption, and adjust your resources requests over time.
The goal is to never leave your nodes be surprised by a memory saturation, because the swap can be fatal for your nodes.